# Hyperledger Fabric Illegal argument exception error

Tags: java, sdk, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using Java SDK of Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.2, I implemented a function that writes on the Hyperledger. For that, I am using: 2 peers, 1 orderer, 1 channel. I tried to run my app but I got this error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The proposal responses have 0 inconsistent groups with 1 that are invalid. Expected all to be consistent and none to be invalid.`

Answer (score 1):

You need your chaincode to be deterministic. I guess that you are sending the transaction to 2 peers and each computes a different chaincode result.

Please edit your question with:

- The endorsement policy you have
- What your chaincode is doing